# Detecting Number of Claps using MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I'd like to detect the number of claps in a given wav file. Here's my first attempt. I can draw the spectogram but how can I print " There is only one clap " or " There are two claps " on the console? And can you suggest any other ways to the same problem? Here is my code:

```
hfile = 'two.wav';

[stereo1, Fs, nbits, readinfo] = wavread(hfile);
mono1 = mean(stereo1,2);

M = round(0.01*Fs); 
N = 2^nextpow2(4*M);
w = hamming(M);

spectrogram(mono1,w,120,N,Fs);
```

Comment: Can anybody help me? Please, it does not seem so hard but I don't know MATLAB well.

Comment: What problem or problems are you having with your code? Is it giving any error messages, and if so what are they? I don't know anything about this, but the information will help others answer your question.

Comment: do you mean `fprintf('There is %i clap(s)\n', clapCount)` ?

Comment: No, the code is correct but it only plots the spectogram. I would like to determine the number of claps in a given wav file and print it on the screen. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by taking the actual output of the spectrogram, rather than just plotting it.

`[S,F,T,P] = spectrogram(mono1,w,120,N,Fs);`

I'm presuming there are obvious features in that spectrogram that you can identify clear as representing a "clap", perhaps some sort of peak of power within a given frequency band. The output `P` represents the power for a given F (set of frequencies) and T (set of times), so you can do things like:

```
% take the segment of P relating to your frequencies of interest
P2 = P(F>thresh_l&F<thresh_h,:); 

%show the mean power in that band over time
m = mean(P2);
plot(T,m);
```

Then you can perhaps look for cases where there is a sudden rise in mean power and count each of those as "one clap". You will have to be careful, particularly if the claps are not well separated, in determining the thresholds.

Comment: Sir, thank you very much for your help. But how can I write "there is one clap" or "there are two claps" on the console. I just want to add this message to my existing code.

Comment: Use `disp` or `fprintf` to show a message.  Gaston already gave one example in comments.

Comment: Ok but how can I determine the number of claps from the spectogram? For example, if there are two peaks in the spectogram, I should write "two claps" on the console. Or if there is only one peak in the spectogram, I should write "one clap". Does the function clapcount counts the number of claps? Thanks.